# SOAP Authentication with pre-encoded authorization string in PHP

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I am working on a simple SOAP request from a server in PHP, using the standard SOAP library calls.  I do not have the required username and password for authorization; however, I do have the base64-encoded authorization string (from a database) that encoding the username and password would provide.  I don't seem to be able to find an example that uses the already-encoded authorization string.  Is there a) a technique I can use that allows and transmits the pre-encoded string, and/or b) a function that allows me to parse out the username and password from the encoded string so I can pass those as params?

TIA for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer:

The base-64 encoded string is simply the login and password encoded.  I just decoded the string using base64_decode and split the string on the semicolon (:) symbol.  Here's what the code looks like -

```
$loginAry = split(":", base64_decode(my_encoded_string_here));
$login = $loginAry[0];
$pwd = $loginAry[1];
```

and used the decoded values to log into the application.  Simple as that.